# How can I review a bad question that has already been downvoted?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I'm reviewing a question (first post), which I think has no quality. If I see the question was down-voted already (and taking into account not to scare off new users) would "no action needed" be the right choice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stackoverflow.com is suffering from significant scaling problems as of late.  At close to 10,000 questions per day, bad content is added at a very high rate.  Unfortunately it takes *five* users with sufficient privileges to vote to close for every *one* user adding bad content.  This of course scales poorly, there are simply not enough users with voting privileges to keep up.

It is important to get this bad content removed again as quickly as possible.  Because it has a knack for multiplying, bad questions tend to produce bad answers that make it more difficult to get rid of the content.  And they take up space on the front page, space that should be reserved for questions that are worth keeping.  Giving them a chance to get enough views to get exposure and a useful answer.

The review queues were added a while ago to try to focus this effort, making it easier for the users with voting privileges to find such bad content.  With the obvious goal to get these users to vote.  Taking no action when you actually see bad content was certainly not the intention.

So recommended actions are:

- Use Skip if you don't know what the question is about and can't figure out whether it is worth keeping or not.  Keep in mind that this is not unusual, there are plenty of questions that require a subject expert to have a shot at understanding what the question is even asking.  That does not make them bad questions.
- Use Delete consistently if you do see a low quality question, like you did here.  Whether this was asked by a new user is of no consequence, we do not pay attention to who asked the question.  Only the content matters.
- If the question looks salvageable and you have the time available then Edit is an option.  Keep in mind that editing takes a much greater effort than voting so brings the scaling problem back in spades.  Only edit when you would have voted "Looks Good" after you're done, the worst possible outcome is that the question gets deleted anyway, in spite of your efforts.

I probably should reiterate over the "scare off new users" angle.  The way StackExchange sites work is counter to what most users believe is "good" for a web site.  With the common idea that getting more users to visit the site to ask questions is beneficial to the site.  The Stackoverflow site in particular is *way* past the break-even point where getting more such users enriches the site.  We're heavily on the right side of that bell curve, having more new users disproportionally adding bad content is not what the site needs to stay healthy.

Keep in mind the SE sites only care about *what* is being asked and answered, *who* asks the question or who answers it is not important.  We are not trying to help *one* user with a problem, we help the next hundred users that have the same problem and google the answer.  Attracting such users with good content is what's good for the site.

Comment: "Only edit when you would have voted "Looks Good" after you're done" is a very important point. One should be jealous of one's time (and votes), and only spend it where it's really going to make a lasting improvement.

Comment: "Unfortunately it takes five users with sufficient privileges to vote to close for every one user adding bad content. This of course scales poorly, there are simply not enough users with voting privileges to keep up." It's even worse than that since it is almost certainly the case that the majority, if not the overwhelming majority, of people with sufficient voting privileges don't participate in that part of the system anyway. The actual ratio is (user+newusers)/(willing active moderators with sufficient privileges).

Answer (score 35):

Try your best not to take others' votes into account when casting your own, regardless of direction. One of the most important features of up and down votes here is that, over time, they reflect the aggregated judgement of a whole lot of experts. (You should especially never try to use your vote to "cancel" or "compensate" for someone else's vote in the opposite direciton.) Vote when you think the post deserves *your* vote.

Cover up the existing score with your hand and judge the post on its own merits. If you believe it's a poor submission to the site, downvote. If you think it's high-quality, upvote it. If you can't really make up your mind, or it's not *that* good or bad, but you see some things that could be improved, comment to explain them.

If you can't see anything useful that you can contribute, then "No action needed" would be the right choice.

Comment: what do you think about to automatically send to the new (1 rep) user a comment with links to the tour" and "how to ask questions", once they get 1 or 2 down-votes?

Comment: Sure, but [there's already a click-through before they can post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84670/159251).

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like a lot of new users just click through, without paying attention, so if their first question would send them back to where they started, maybe they pay more attention to it?

Comment: If you think the new question is bad and the user needs to go back to the help pages, you can post a comment yourself.

Comment: I don't know.  While I agree that you shouldn't generally let the current score of a post affect your assessment of it, I do feel that in this case considering the current state of the votes is reasonable.  After a certain point a respectful, negative response turns into a dogpile.  I like the phrasing on [this answer regarding plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered/160072#160072): "Don't be a lynch mob"

Comment: I think the notion of "Just judge it own your own" is quite theoretical and not helpful in many circumstances. What is the point of downvoting a poor question of a new user, which already has 5 downvotes? Of course I would downvote it when it would have a non-negative total, but I think there are a lot of cases were the point is already been made and there is no need to further punish new users.

Comment: Agree with ignoring other votes. I personally go a step further and won't let the rep/age/etc of the user influence my voting as I expect the same standards from everyone. That a user is new to SE or maybe the whole internet is no excuse for not bothering to learn about the site - research is expected before asking a question, and research about SO itself should IMO be included here. Of course I leave (or upvote existing) comments educating OP, but there are places where OP would only get downvoted and told "lurk more", which is IMO not even that unreasonable as it's at least efficient...

Comment: And @dirkk, why do you see downvotes as "punishment"? A downvote simply means "this post is bad". A lot of downvotes means a lot of users agree about this. As long as there are comments explaining to OP why he is downvoted (given OP's not been here for a long enough time that he should know better) this is for the best of both the site and the user. I think it's critical for users to understand that downvotes are not personal but simply an indication that a post has issues; if someone leaves because of downvotes he hasn't understood SO. And a lot of downvotes bring this point across faster.

Comment: Sure, @dirkk; one has a limited number of votes per day, and probably beating the dead horse of post that's already at -5 with another downvote isn't worth spending one of those on. In that case, "No action [is] needed". Punishment is not the point of downvotes, however; they are directed squarely at the content.

Comment: @l4mpi I didn't wrote "punishment" and I agree with you that a downvote is not a punishment. However, the user is losing reputation, hence he is punished (there actually is a difference between _getting a punishment_ and _being punished_). Also, they same holds in my opinion for comments: If people already explained, what the OP did wrong there is no need to repeat the same thing over and over again: The point has been made, so move on.

Comment: @dirkk This is the same fallacy, just taken a step further - how is losing imaginary internet points "being punished"? There are two cases here; (1) the user is new and doesn't have much to lose or (2) the user has been here a while and should know better, and thus it's fully justified that he loses reputation. And AFAIK the user can even fully regain the rep by deleting his question. Also, questions very rarely hit -10 and I've never seen one below -12 (which were always extremely bad questions by 1-rep users btw), which is 20 rep or 4/2 upvotes on a question/answer, not a huge amount at all.

Comment: On the other hand, counter-upvotes from well-meaning people are a way worse problem IMO. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16915707/1110381), which is at -2 - not that bad until you see that it has 6 downvotes and 4 upvotes. And this was the score before OP edited in his meager try; look at revision 3 and ask yourself why anybody, let alone 4 different users, would ever upvote this...

Comment: @l4mpi I really don't care about rep (Why? the brilliant Morozov explains all the reasons why I think gamification is stupid), my point is not about losing rep and whether this is bad or not. However, voting down is some form of negative feedback (meaning: I don't like your question) and I think there is no point at all in repeating the same thing over and over again (here: many users downvoting). As Einstein said, insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.

Comment: So I see no point in downvoting when I see there are already 3 or 4 downvotes there. I simply do nothing. Of course I also do not upvote, there is not reason to do that and I agree with you that I have no idea who would ever upvote such questions. However, I haven't seen this regularly on SO.

Answer (score 9):

Not necessarily. You could leave a comment on the post, telling the user what they could do to improve their contribution.

Receiving downvotes, then your post simply getting deleted isn't a great feedback loop to improve, otherwise.

You could also flag to close. This would route the post into the "Close Vote Queue".

Comment: "no action needed" doesn't feel the right choice, but "down-vote" neither, and "skip" would mean I've no opinion on that matter

Comment: I'd prefer to let a new user know about "the tour" and "how to ask questions". maybe if a new user (1 rep) receives a down-vote, he should automatically receive a link to these topics (and maybe earn a badge?)

Comment: @Vikel: It's up to you what you leave in your comment! By all means you can link to the tour or how to ask page. Personally, I try to be as specific and relevant to the user as I can be, rather than linking them to generic pages, but as I said... it's entirely up to you :)

Answer (score 4):

If a post is of very low quality, you should down vote it. Regardless of how others have voted and regardless of what some edit may achieve. If you just silently edit the post to fix the problems, the poster will learn nothing from it.

If they are only struggling with site features like using the correct tags or code formatting, that is usually not a reason to down vote, you can edit and then leave a comment explaining how those things should be used.

There's not really a direct connection between voting and editing. Except of course, once a poorly-written post has been correctly edited, it will less likely receive down votes, because people tend to judge a post as it currently stands.

Comment: +1 but "If they are only struggling with site features like using the correct tags or code formatting" they should IMO still be downvoted for this, given it's not just a minor issue in an otherwise ok question. A badly formatted question is a badly formatted question, no matter who the Author is; and it usually indicates carelessness as there is a preview of the post and extensive formatting/tagging help available while writing a question. If they're reasonably new to the site I'd of course leave a comment telling them how to use formatting/tagging/etc and linking to the appropriate help page.

Answer (score -4):

For down-voting, don't down-vote a question if you believe the amount of down-votes has satisfied the awfulness of the question. Let's say someone has a question that asks:`How to make the purple dinosaurs in my program roar?` Then you decide that the question deserves `x` down-votes. If the vote total is more than `x`, then down-vote it. However, make sure to keep in mind to not up-vote it, since a question like that deserves absolutely no up-votes.

Let's say you have a TON of time to make that question actually half decent. Do not up-vote it after you are done. Instead you should down-vote it, since you took the time to make it actually good from something terrible. The person who asked that question does not deserve to get any positive feedback for that question, instead they should understand that it is a awful question and that they need to do better next time. If you up-vote it, the person will think that no matter how horrible the question is, someone will fix it up and say that they are great. New users need to understand that people will help them, but the question must be made well.

FYI: This is just expanding upon the other answers. This is not meant to be something completely new.