# Do you (or would you) downvote a question or answer before giving the deciding vote to delete it?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, post-ban, vote-to-delete

There are times when I'll be browsing my favorite tags and find an extremely downvoted question which is closed and has a few delete votes. I'll typically read the post and, if appropriate, downvote and vote to delete.

I feel that the downvote might be overdoing it. We're already getting rid of the bad content by deleting it. Should I also try and make sure that this user never posts again?

In my opinion, for new users, a +/-1 (ex. -6 vs -5) on a deleted question won't be the tipping point that convinces them to improve the content they post. In those cases, the vote is simply for the system and its banning algorithms.

Should we pile on with the punishment or should we be satisfied that the content is removed?

(The same should apply to answers.)

Related:

- [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Do you mean in a review queue?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't spend time in the review queue, but I would assume the same applies there. I meant just regular browsing of questions in my favorite tags.

Comment: Unless it's a case of a senseless spam (like those stupid posts unearthing tech support phone numbers) or some completely undecipherable garbage I usually do not downvote any heavily downvoted questions.

Comment: if question deserve downvote no matter weather i cast delete vote or not but i definitively down vote.

Comment: @PM77-1 So you're saying you downvote the stuff that doesn't need to be downvoted, but don't downvote the stuff that actually needs to be downvoted?

Comment: @Servy - I'm saying that unless I want the question to disappear immediately by exceeding negative threshold, I do not see any practical reason to further downvote already heavily downvoted question.

Comment: It doesn't accomplish much, you just put the guy in a deeper hole after he gets question-banned.  Given the lack of willingness from SE to actively block banned users from creating a new account, you are just making it more likely that he creates one.

Comment: The number of votes (up or down) shouldn't influence your vote.

Comment: Related: [How can I review a bad question that has already been downvoted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251911)

Comment: It probably matters little. If it's on the edge of closure just close and move on

Comment: @kevin Assuming I had decided that I wanted to delete a post, should I also downvote it? (I don't care how many downvotes it has.) Do I accomplish anything by doing so?

Comment: If it's downvoted and has no upvoted answers, do you really need to cast a delete vote on it? (should get deleted automatically.) If it has an upvoted answer (meaning a useful answer), does it need to be deleted?

Comment: I find delete votes to be the least used vote type for my general site usage, the only time i'll vote to delete something is if it's an answer that is absolutely wrong *and* harmful. i find it hard to come up with a justifiable reason to delete a question rather than just closing it.

Comment: Don't forget that some users have the "down vote" but not the "close" privilege. If I read it well, down votes are for questions that _"does no shows any research effort; it is unclear of not useful"_. However, without the required privileges, some users might be tempted to down-vote a post that should be only closed (say: a clear and well written question but unfortunately off-topic ). Unless we are considering _"not useful"_ as a synonym for _"should be closed"_ ?

Comment: So you are seriously "punishing" other users?

Comment: @Giosco I don't know if that's the right word, but I would imagine that's how those users would see it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I never consciously evaluate whether, given all the **other** votes on the post, **my** vote is needed. If a post sits at +300, but, according to the same principles I apply to all posts, I find that it merits a downvote, then I will downvote. If it merits an upvote, I will upvote. If a post sits at -300, and I find that it merits an upvote, then I will upvote. If it merits a downvote, I will downvote.

That a post is about to be deleted changes nothing to this. Keep in mind that a terrible post that has been deleted may be undeleted by the community, and **still** be terrible.

Comment: Havent't yet found one at -300... where did you?

Comment: Just number I pulled out of thin air. I'm guessing most posts get deleted before they reach -300.

Comment: @Deduplicator, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly) is the lowest voted question that is still undeleted on SO.

Comment: @Andy asked by what might just be one of the largest help vampires stackoverflow has ever known

Comment: @royhowie what is a "help vampire"? That sounds a bit mean.

Comment: @Thomas http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: @Deduplicator There is [this post on meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274959/3488231) at -263... I guess we could make it happen? (For reference, lowest scoring post on SO is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-4729670) with -166 (got that from data.SE) and lowest scoring post on meta.SE is [a post by Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/259700) at -211.)

Answer (score 17):

> We're already getting rid of the bad content by deleting it. Should I also try and make sure that this user never posts again?

You should make sure that if the user continues to contribute very low quality content *continuously* and isn't learning from their mistakes and improving, despite many warnings and systems in place to help them learn, that they end up banned, yes.

If you don't do that then you'll just need to keep getting rid of the same users same bad content over and over again.

Comment: For these new users without proper usernames, it's hard to keep track. And if all their content is deleted, you can't really tell.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Which is exactly why you should just downvote all of the unhelpful content.  These automated quality tools are specifically designed to keep track of which users are and are not improving, can incorporate deleted content, have a consistent standard, etc. *so that you don't have to*.  You can just vote on posts based on their merits, and the system will take care of the rest.  When you start not voting on posts then the system isn't fed the information it needs, and it can't make the right call.

Answer (score 5):

Things that aren't fixable get immediate down-votes. If the Asker's rep implies they know they shouldn't have asked the question the way they did, I immediately down-vote even if it's fixable. Sometimes I'll both down-vote and flag a new user's question.

However, I will sometimes flag and leave a comment telling the Asker how they should improve their question but hold off on down-voting. If they've fixed it in a day or so, fine. If they post a reply telling me why they won't fix their question (which happens more often than I expected it to) then I down-vote.

I'm not recommending that other people do this though. I don't think there ought to be an expectation that anyone will follow up on a low quality question.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I am impressed that you asked, it shows that you ultimately care about users that might not be up to par and that's a rare thing around here.

As for your question, I'd like to throw in my (probably unpopular) suggestion. If  a **question** has received 3 or more down votes and is at -3 score or less and is worth deleting, simply delete vote and move on. What Servy said it sometimes true:

> If you don't do that then you'll just need to keep getting rid of the same users same bad content over and over again.

but, ultimately, deciding a users ban fate on one question is really not fair. The ban will happen if they keep posting bad content, but I think that it's okay to extend them some good faith by not downvoting their post to oblivion. I have never been downvoted to that extreme, but I can certainly imagine how disheartening that would be. The one exception to this, of course, would be spam. Burn it with fire, downvote, and flag, etc.

As for answers, this doesn't really apply because bad answers can do different damage.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think anyone is q-banned based on just a single question.