# Should I choose "No Action Needed" in reviews when someone else has already given adequate feedback?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251911/how-can-i-review-a-bad-question-that-has-already-been-downvoted) but I still need some clarification.

Maybe I'm wrong but I only upvote questions on SE that I think are ... unique? Good? I don't cast an upvote based on whether or not questions *can* be answered.

When applying that concept to a review, what are the implications of "No Action Needed" on questions where there is already adequate feedback from other members? I wouldn't downvote the question and someone has already commented. Should I just skip the question?

In this particular case, I'm referring mostly to the First Posts queue. The question generally doesn't merit a downvote but needs clarification, which another user has already asked for.

Comment: If the question can't be answered because it requires clarification, then you should be voting to close the question.  That's literally *exactly* what the "unclear' reason exists for.  You should also be downvoting the question, as a question being unclear is one of the primary reasons for downvoting a question.  Doing nothing for an unclear question is not appropriate.

Comment: I'll run out of flags *very* quickly on the First Posts queue. That makes sense though. Thanks

Comment: If you're out of flags then stop using the queue.  Your *primary* purpose in that queue is to flag posts that merit it.

Comment: You get 100 flags a day, and 20 reviews. Don't worry about running out. :)

Comment: I only have 10 and 20 reviews.

Comment: *"Maybe I'm wrong but I only upvote questions on SE that I think are ... unique? Good? I don't cast an upvote based on whether or not questions can be answered. "*  - you vote based on the quality, which is a good practice. I hope you downvote poor quality questions/answers too :)

Comment: Yeah, of course.